# Do docker layers allow for unintended container OS upgrades?

Tags: docker, containers, dockerhub

As I move to containers, I am realizing that the container concept ties the OS and the Application into the same deployment system.

### Background

> docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1.1-buster-slim

This command pulls the container image setup by Microsoft for the .NET Core Runtime.  That container image depends on the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime-deps:3.1-buster-slim` container image.  And that runtime-deps container image is built from the `debian:buster-slim` image.

The `debian:buster-slim` image currently targets version 10.2 of Linux Debian.  But when 10.3 is released it will target 10.3.  (And I assume it targeted 10.1 when it was the current release.)

### Question

When the `buster-slim` tag of `debian` gets updated to target 10.3, do all downloads of `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1.1-buster-slim` get updated to start using 10.3?

Or is `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1.1-buster-slim` somehow locked in at 10.2?

I am worried about something like this happening:

1. I make a container that depends on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1.1-buster-slim` and release it to production (which runs Debian 10.2)
2. Debian releases 10.3 of their OS and update the `buster-slim` tag to point to 10.3.
3. I do a very minor change to my container (from step 1), rebuild the container image and deploy it.  But because of how docker works, my minor change also includes an unintended OS upgrade to Debian 10.3.

I expect something like this when using the tag `latest`, but not when I am using a specific tag.

So this can be summed up with this question:

**Am I going to get dependency upgrades for a tag, even if I keep using the exact same tag?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, potentially. Nothing in Docker prevents authors from uploading a new image to the same tag multiple times, even for the specific tags like you're talking about here.